# How develop Android applications?

Tags: android, titanium

I'm really new with this thing of "Android development" and I was really excited when I found [Appcelerator Titanium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appcelerator_Titanium), but now I got the big surprise, it doesn't work on my computer. What other alternatives are there for Android development specially if they include HTML, JavaScript and CSS for creating such applications?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for alternatives to the standard Java development of Android applications? Is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

Everything you need to know is on the official site http://developer.android.com/

Answer (score 3):

There is a very popular alternative for making Android and iOS apps with only HTML and JavaScript. It is called [PhoneGap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneGap):

http://www.phonegap.com/

I think it is exactly what your looking for.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

My first port of call would be to try and get on the trial of Google App Inventor. It's a really neat way of making Android apps. You can find out more here: http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/about/

Answer (score 1):

A list of various alternative web-tech-based development frameworks is here
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_phone_web_based_application_framework

having said that, I have succeeded in running Titanium on Vista and Ubuntu, so if you post the error you are getting someone might be able to help.

App Inventor is fun, although it isn't Javascript based.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try out Unify, a framework for developing web apps for major platforms (in the moment iOS, Android, webOS - more coming in the future). It is open source and has been released a few days ago. :-)

- http://www.unify-project.org/
- http://www.unify-training.com/

Answer (score 0):

Get the SL4A app for android. It lets you run python scripts on your android.
Also, look into webview. It let's you load html.